# Custom Bundle Pricing In Admin Order

Tags: magento-enterprise, price, adminhtml, bundled-product, ee-1.14.1

We used to have code that allowed us to add a custom price to a bundle.  As of an upgrade to 1.14.1.0 that code no longer works.

To get started we started tinkering with the core code to enable the custom option (`app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Create\Items\Grid.php` )
I the "`canApplyCustomPrice`" function, I allowed bundles to return true.

That enables the "**custom price**" edit box on the admin order form, however any value you add to it, will apply to that row.

How can I get the custom price to apply to the bundle product?

Answer (score 0):

We've had to write a plugin to solve the issue.  The details are listed on our [blog post](http://www.silvatechsolutions.com/tech-news/magento-ee-custom-bundle-pricing-admin/)

Comment: With just the link which may be dead at some point, this does not really qualify as an answer. Could you add at least a summary of the blog post? Then feel free to accept your own answer ;)